# How do I refactor to avoid passing functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, refactoring

I currently have code that acquires and manipulates data from multiple sources using pandas DataFrames. The intent is for a user to create an instance of a class (call it `dbase`) which provides methods to do things like acquire and store data from API queries. I'm doing this by allowing the user to define their own functions to format values in `dbase`, but I've found that I tend to pass those user-defined functions through several other functions in ways that get confusing. I think this must be an obvious mistake to someone who knows what they're doing but I haven't come up with a better way to give the user control of the data.

The API queries are the worst example right now. Say I want to get a name from a server. Right now I do something like the following, in which the user-defined function for transforming the name gets passed across three other functions before it's called.

```
# file with code for api interaction
def submitter(this_query, dbase, name_mangler):
    new_data = api.submit(this_query)
    new_dbase_entry = name_mangler(new_data)
    # in reality there is much more complicated data transformation here
    dbase.update(new_dbase_entry)

def query_api(dbase, meta, name_mangler):
    queries = make_query_strings(dbase, meta)
    # using pandas.DataFrame.apply() here to avoid a for loop
    queries.apply(lambda x: submitter(x, dbase))
```

```
# other file with class definition
from api_code import query_api

class dbase():

    __init__():
        self.df = pandas.DataFrame()
        # data gets moved around between more than one data
        # structure in this class, I'm just using a single
        # dataframe as a minimal example

    def get_remote_data(self, meta, name_mangler):
        # in reality there is code here to handle multiple
        # cases here rather than a trivial wrapper for another
        # function
        query_api(self, meta, name_mangler)

    def update(self, new_data):
        # do consistency checks
        # possibly write new dbase entry
```

A user would then do something like this

```
import dbase

def custom_mangler(name):
    # User determines how to store the name in dbase
    # for instance this could take "Grace Hopper" to "hopper"
    return(mangled_name)

my_dbase = dbase.dbase()
# meta defines what needs to be queried and how the remote
# data should get processed into dbase
meta = {stuff} 
my_dbase.get_remote_data(meta, custom_mangler)
```

I find it very hard to follow my own code here because the definitions of functions can be widely separated from the first point at which they're called. How should I refactor to address this problem? (and does this approach violate accepted coding patterns for other reasons?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to infer context from what you've posted, so take this with a grain of salt. The general concepts still apply. Also take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as this question might be a better fit for that site.

Two things come to mind.

1. Try to give your functions/classes/variables better names
2. Think about orthogonality

## Good Names

Consider how this looks from a users perspective. `dbase` is not a very descriptive name for either the module or the class. `meta` doesn't tell me at all what the dict should contain. `mangler` tells me that the string gets changed, but nothing about where the string comes from or how it should be changed.

Good names are **hard**, but it's worth spending time to make them thoughtful. It's always a trade off between being descriptive and overly verbose. If you can't think of a name that gives clear meaning without taking up too much space, then consider if your API is overly complex. Always consider names from the end users perspective as well as future programmers who will be reading/maintaining your code.

## Orthogonality

Following the Unix mantra of "do one thing and do it well", sometimes an API is simpler and more flexible if we separate out different tasks to different functions rather than having one function that does it all.

When writing code, I think "what is the minimum this function needs to do to be useful".

In your example

```
my_dbase.get_remote_data(meta, custom_mangler)
```

`get_remote_data` not only fetches the data, but also processes it. That can be confusing as a user. There's a lot happening behind the scenes in this function that isn't obvious from the function name.

It might be more appropriate to have separate function calls for this. Let's assume that you're querying weather servers about temperature and rainfall.

```
london_weather_data = weatheraggrigator.WeatherAggrigator()
reports = london_weather_data.fetch_weather_reports(sources=[server_a, server_b])
london_weather_data.process_reports(reports, short_name_formatter)
```

Yes it's longer to type, but as a user it's a big improvement as I know what I'm getting.

Ultimately you need to decide where to split up tasks. The above may not make sense for your application.

Comment: Thanks, helpful advice. The names here are entirely made up for the example. This is by far the most complicated project I've ever tried to code myself and it took me quite a while to distill the skeleton in the post so I could ask about one thing instead of making people wade through all the other components involved (which I guess means orthogonality should be a priority).